# Shift Elements of 2D VBA Array

Tags: arrays, vba

All -

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to "shift" elements of a 2-dimensional array.  Effectively, what I have is triangular data, saved in a VBA array (n x m, where n <= m):

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5
  ----------------
  0 | A B C D E F
  1 | G H I J
  2 | K L
```

I'd like to "restructure" this array to:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5
  ----------------
  0 | A B C D E F
  1 |     G H I J
  2 |         K L
```

The blank values in the array are actually empty strings ("").  I'd imagine there's some looping that I could do to perform this with some compute cost, but I'm wondering if there's an efficient approach for subset "shifting" within VBA...

Comment: There's no one-liner for this - you will need to use a loop approach.

Comment: Allow me a question: could you test my answer to the shift array elements question? I posted an approach reducing loops to a minimum; if helpful feel free to upvorte and/or accept by ticking the green checkmark :-) @Mykenk

Answer (score 0):

As @TimWilliams commented correctly, you won't do it without any loops. - A possible approach, however reducing loops would be to

- write the initial array (named e.g. `v`) **row wise** to an empty target range (applying individual offsets you can calculate before) and eventually
- assign them back as so called *data field* array.

The following example code should give you an idea. - Little draw back: in any case you get the array back as 1-based array.

```
        '~~> assign initial (variant) array v as in OP
        '...
        '~~> calculate column offsets per array row, e.g. {0,2,4}
        '...

        '~~> shift array rows and write them to any empty target area
        Dim startCell As Range: Set startCell = Sheet1.Range("X1")
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As Variant
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            '~~> get individual column offset per row, e.g. {0,2,4}
            j = Array(0, 2, 4)(i - 1)
            '~~> write next row to target range
            startCell.Offset(i, j).Resize(1, UBound(v, 2)) = Application.Index(v, i, 0)
        Next i
        '~~> get rearranged 1-based 2-dim datafield array
        v = startCell.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2))
```

If you shift elements within a greater array, you could write the entire array to the target and overwrite only rows you need rearranged (considering to clear these single row ranges before:-)